# How to use SDL with gcc?

Tags: gcc, compilation, sdl

I download SDL source at 'https://www.libsdl.org'

I use cmake and get library.

```
libSDL2.a
libSDL2main.a
libSDL2-2.0.so
libSDL2-2.0.so.0
libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.0
```

I write main.c to test SDL.

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I make lib directory.
I move *.a file and include directory.

```
vim main.c
mkdir lib
mv libSDL2.a libSDL2main.a ./lib
mv /home/gakgu/다운로드/SDL2-2.0.4/include ./
```

Then try compile.

```
gcc -W -Wall -o main main.c -Iinclude -Llib -lSDL2 -lSDL2main
```

[but It is failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gywf5.png)

What's the problem?

Comment: If you link with static library you're supposed to pull all its dependencies (in that given case it is `-lpthread`, but there may be more). Shared libraries have dependency information embedded so it isn't requred.

Answer (score 3):

You must add `-lpthread` before other libs to link threading support.

You should also enable a bit more warning option: `-Wextra` `-pedantic`

So

```
gcc -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main main.c -Iinclude -lpthread -Llib -lSDL2 -lSDL2main
```