# Why doesn't gcc link an SDL 2.0 C project? (macOS)

Tags: c, gcc, sdl-2

I wrote a simple Chip-8 emulator in C (mostly taking inspiration from [this](https://github.com/JamesGriffin/CHIP-8-Emulator); to be honest, just rewriting it in C). It uses SDL 2.0, which I definitely have installed.

As I tried compiling the files (`gcc main.c chip8.c -o chip8`), I got this stack of errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_CreateRenderer", referenced from:
      _main in main-638d2a.o
  "_SDL_CreateTexture", referenced from:
      _main in main-638d2a.o
  "_SDL_CreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main-638d2a.o
  "_SDL_GetError", referenced from:
      _main in main-638d2a.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in main-638d2a.o
  "_SDL_PollEvent", referenced from:
      _main in main-638d2a.o
  "_SDL_RenderClear", referenced from:
      _main in main-638d2a.o
  "_SDL_RenderCopy", referenced from:
      _main in main-638d2a.o
  "_SDL_RenderPresent", referenced from:
      _main in main-638d2a.o
  "_SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize", referenced from:
      _main in main-638d2a.o
  "_SDL_UpdateTexture", referenced from:
      _main in main-638d2a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm very sure I used the correct #include (`#include "SDL2/SDL.h"`). This is my project structure:

```
chip-8
—— main.c
–– chip8.c
–– chip8.h
–– INVADERS (rom file)
```

Why doesn't the linker work with this? Are any other compiler flags required?

Comment: Inclusion is not linking, "installing" a library is just copying it to your hard drive.  You have to explicitly tell the linker which non-default libraries you are linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't the linker work with this? Are any other compiler flags required?

Yes, you need to tell the linker which libraries to link against, e.g.:

```
-lSDL2
```

See [How to use SDL with gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082665/how-to-use-sdl-with-gcc)

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. A flag is what I thought was missing, yet I wasn't able to find any information on it.